# Fullscreen not working in xmonad

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, xmonad, gedit, fullscreen

I am using Arch Linux (**4.7.5-1-ARCH**) with xmonad (**xmonad 0.12**) window manager. I am new to xmonad and I am still learning it. I have not done much modifications so my `xmonad.hs` is minimal.

```hs
 import XMonad  
 import XMonad.Layout.Spacing  
 import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86  
 import XMonad.Util.EZConfig  
 import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers

 manageHook = manageDocks <+> (isFullscreen --> doFullFloat) <+> manageHook defaultConfig   
 myLayout = tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| Full  
  where  
      -- default tiling algorithm partitions the screen into two panes  
      tiled = spacing 3 $ Tall nmaster delta ratio  

      -- The default number of windows in the master pane  
      nmaster = 1  

      -- Default proportion of screen occupied by master pane  
      ratio = 1/2  

      -- Percent of screen to increment by when resizing panes  
      delta = 2/100  

 main = do  
 xmonad $ defaultConfig  
      {layoutHook = myLayout


 }
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to make some applications go full screen. As of now, when I press <kbd>F11</kbd>, only mozilla firefox goes to fullscreen. The following applications (and many more) does not obey <kbd>F11</kbd> at all.
 - gedit text editor
 - evince Document Viewer
 - emacs
 - leafpad

Nothing happens when I press <kbd>F11</kbd>. It doesn't respond even if I manually click on fullscreen-button <kbd>⇱⇲</kbd> (as you can see below).

[image]

Is there any way to make things go fullscreen on xmonad ?

Comment: The whole of that screenshot is occupied by a single window.  What do you want differently, from "fullscreen"?

Comment: @JigglyNaga something like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/daHWI.png

Comment: I got the solution from #xmonad IRC :) . He told me he would post an answer here too.

Comment: @Severus Tux , of course is helpful write answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply add [XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops.fullscreenEventHook](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Hooks-EwmhDesktops.html) to your handleEventHook definition. Here is an excerpt from my [configuration](https://github.com/Chedi/xmonad/blob/master/xmonad.hs)

```
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

main = do
    xmonad $ docks $ ewmh def {
        handleEventHook    = handleEventHook def <+> XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops.fullscreenEventHook,
        modMask            = mod4Mask,
        terminal           = "terminator",
        workspaces         = myWorkspaces,
        layoutHook         = myLayoutHook,
        manageHook         = manageSpawn <+> myManageHook <+> manageHook def,
        borderWidth        = 1,
        normalBorderColor  = black,
        focusedBorderColor = yellow,
        focusFollowsMouse  = False,
        logHook            = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP {
            ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc,
            ppTitle  = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 50}
        }`additionalKeys`
```